# how to count characters in all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to count characters (without spaces) in all `divs` and only in `divs`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
<div>a</div>
<div>b4</div>
<div>52 5</div>
<hr>
<input type='text' value='323'>

</div>
```

```
let x = // count characters in all divs;
console.log(x);
```

In the above example result should be `6`

Any idea?

Comment: Wow, a question that translates to "please do my work for me" actually gets upvoted...

Comment: @Utkanos, of course, and plus - has 6 answers. You will never understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop over all the `div`s and get the text context. Then, split it using whitespace to get array or each word and then add the length of that word to `x` to get total characters in all `div`s.

```js
var x = 0;
$('.parent div').each(function(){
  $(this).text().split(/\s/g).forEach(word => x+=word.trim().length);
});
console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b4</div>
  <div>52 5</div>
  <hr>
  <input type='text' value='323'>

</div>
```

Comment: @qadenza glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Get text of parent and then remove unnecessary chars

```js
var originalText = $('.parent').text()
var cleanText = originalText.replace(/[^\w]/g, '')

console.log(cleanText.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
<div>a</div>
<div>b4</div>
<div>52 5</div>
<hr>
<input type='text' value='323'>

</div>
```

Comment: This is not a proper solution. This will not work if there is text content outside the `div` like `<div>56</div>123456`. OP needs the length of text inside `div`s

Answer (score 1):

Get all the divs which have not a div inside, and get the text of them.

Then remove spaces.

```js
console.log($('div:not(:has(div))').text().replace(/\s/g,'').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
<div>a</div>
<div>b4</div>
<div>52 5</div>
<hr>
<input type='text' value='323'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop `parent` class and find `div` ;  get `length` and add your length using `parseInt` and `+=`  like below.

```js
var total = 0;
$('.parent').find('div').each(function(index, element) {
  total += parseInt($(this).text().replace(/\s/g,"").length);
});
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b4</div>
  <div>52 5</div>
  <hr>
  <input type='text' value='323'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the text from a div using `text()` method in `jQuery`.

like below `$('.parent').text()`.

Now replace all the spaces with empty char

```
$('.parent').text().replace(/\s/g,'')
```

Now get the length of the resultant

```
$('.parent').text().replace(/\s/g,'').length
```

Here is the full demo

```js
console.log($('.parent').text().replace(/\s/g,'').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
<div>a</div>
<div>b4</div>
<div>52 5</div>
<hr>
<input type='text' value='323'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's implement `.replaceAll()`:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

#### Pure JS solution:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var sum = 0;
for (var index = 0; index < divs.length; index++) sum = divs[index].replaceAll(" ", "").length;
```

#### jquery solution

You can achieve the same using `.text()` and `$("div")`

#### Potential problem

You might have `div`s inside other `div`s. If that is the case, then you want to avoid counting the `length` of a `div` multiple times (when you reach the `div` itself and when you read the inner text of it wrapper `div`(s)). For this purpose you will need to use the particular information of your case to cope with the situation.